# Saving and loading a form in PyQt5 with QFormBuilder

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm trying to save my form and load it later, but even after following the Qt docs (https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractformbuilder.html), I just get an empty window and an error message: "QFormBuilder was unable to create a widget of the class 'Window'." when loading the .ui file.

Here is a saver:

```
from PyQt5.QtDesigner import QFormBuilder
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
import sys

class Window(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        label = QLabel(self, text = 'myForm')
        self.setWindowTitle('myTitle')
        
        formBuilder = QFormBuilder()
        file = QFile('line_up.ui')
        file.open(QFile.WriteOnly)
        formBuilder.save(file, self)
        file.close()

app = QApplication([])
mainWindow = Window()
mainWindow.show()
app.exec()
```

and here is my loader:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QFile
from PyQt5.QtDesigner import QFormBuilder
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QWidget, QVBoxLayout

#from Qt docs
class MyForm(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        formBuilder = QFormBuilder()
        file = QFile('line_up.ui')
        file.open(QFile.ReadOnly)
        widget = QWidget()
        widget = formBuilder.load(file, self)
        file.close()

##

app = QApplication([])
mainWindow = MyForm()
mainWindow.show()
app.exec()
```

and here is the .ui file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class></class>
 <widget class="Window">
  <property name="styleSheet">
   <string notr="true"/>
  </property>
  <property name="unifiedTitleAndToolBarOnMac">
   <bool>false</bool>
  </property>
  <property name="baseSize">
   <size>
    <width>0</width>
    <height>0</height>
   </size>
  </property>
  <property name="palette">
   <palette>
    <active/>
    <inactive/>
    <disabled/>
   </palette>
  </property>
  <property name="sizeIncrement">
   <size>
    <width>0</width>
    <height>0</height>
   </size>
  </property>
  <property name="windowModality">
   <enum>Qt::NonModal</enum>
  </property>
  <property name="tabShape">
   <enum>QTabWidget::Rounded</enum>
  </property>
  <property name="font">
   <font/>
  </property>
  <property name="maximumWidth">
   <number>16777215</number>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>myTitle</string>
  </property>
  <property name="size" stdset="0">
   <size>
    <width>640</width>
    <height>480</height>
   </size>
  </property>
  <property name="layoutDirection">
   <enum>Qt::LeftToRight</enum>
  </property>
  <property name="dockNestingEnabled">
   <bool>false</bool>
  </property>
  <property name="maximumSize">
   <size>
    <width>16777215</width>
    <height>16777215</height>
   </size>
  </property>
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>640</width>
    <height>480</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="whatsThis">
   <string/>
  </property>
  <property name="cursor">
   <cursorShape>ArrowCursor</cursorShape>
  </property>
  <property name="sizePolicy">
   <sizepolicy hsizetype="Preferred" vsizetype="Preferred">
    <horstretch>0</horstretch>
    <verstretch>0</verstretch>
   </sizepolicy>
  </property>
  <property name="focusPolicy">
   <enum>Qt::NoFocus</enum>
  </property>
  <property name="enabled">
   <bool>true</bool>
  </property>
  <property name="autoFillBackground">
   <bool>false</bool>
  </property>
  <property name="windowModified">
   <bool>false</bool>
  </property>
  <property name="updatesEnabled">
   <bool>true</bool>
  </property>
  <property name="iconSize">
   <size>
    <width>24</width>
    <height>24</height>
   </size>
  </property>
  <property name="toolTipDuration">
   <number>-1</number>
  </property>
  <property name="tabletTracking">
   <bool>false</bool>
  </property>
  <property name="contextMenuPolicy">
   <enum>Qt::DefaultContextMenu</enum>
  </property>
  <property name="locale">
   <locale language="English" country="UnitedKingdom"/>
  </property>
  <property name="windowIconText">
   <string/>
  </property>
  <property name="toolTip">
   <string/>
  </property>
  <property name="accessibleName">
   <string/>
  </property>
  <property name="documentMode">
   <bool>false</bool>
  </property>
  <property name="pos" stdset="0">
   <point>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
   </point>
  </property>
  <property name="minimumWidth">
   <number>0</number>
  </property>
  <property name="windowFilePath">
   <string/>
  </property>
  <property name="maximumHeight">
   <number>16777215</number>
  </property>
  <property name="objectName">
   <string notr="true"/>
  </property>
  <property name="toolButtonStyle">
   <enum>Qt::ToolButtonIconOnly</enum>
  </property>
  <property name="windowOpacity">
   <double>1.000000000000000</double>
  </property>
  <property name="mouseTracking">
   <bool>false</bool>
  </property>
  <property name="statusTip">
   <string/>
  </property>
  <property name="accessibleDescription">
   <string/>
  </property>
  <property name="inputMethodHints">
   <enum>Qt::ImhNone</enum>
  </property>
  <property name="acceptDrops">
   <bool>false</bool>
  </property>
  <property name="minimumSize">
   <size>
    <width>0</width>
    <height>0</height>
   </size>
  </property>
  <property name="minimumHeight">
   <number>0</number>
  </property>
  <property name="animated">
   <bool>true</bool>
  </property>
  <property name="visible">
   <bool>false</bool>
  </property>
  <layout class="QMainWindowLayout" name="_layout">
   <property name="objectName">
    <string notr="true">_layout</string>
   </property>
   <property name="margin">
    <number>11</number>
   </property>
   <property name="sizeConstraint">
    <enum>QLayout::SetDefaultConstraint</enum>
   </property>
   <property name="spacing">
    <number>6</number>
   </property>
  </layout>
  <widget class="QLabel">
   <property name="styleSheet">
    <string notr="true"/>
   </property>
   <property name="textFormat">
    <enum>Qt::AutoText</enum>
   </property>
   <property name="baseSize">
    <size>
     <width>0</width>
     <height>0</height>
    </size>
   </property>
   <property name="text">
    <string>myForm</string>
   </property>
   <property name="palette">
    <palette>
     <active/>
     <inactive/>
     <disabled/>
    </palette>
   </property>
   <property name="sizeIncrement">
    <size>
     <width>0</width>
     <height>0</height>
    </size>
   </property>
   <property name="windowModality">
    <enum>Qt::NonModal</enum>
   </property>
   <property name="font">
    <font/>
   </property>
   <property name="maximumWidth">
    <number>16777215</number>
   </property>
   <property name="margin">
    <number>0</number>
   </property>
   <property name="windowTitle">
    <string/>
   </property>
   <property name="size" stdset="0">
    <size>
     <width>100</width>
     <height>30</height>
    </size>
   </property>
   <property name="layoutDirection">
    <enum>Qt::LeftToRight</enum>
   </property>
   <property name="openExternalLinks">
    <bool>false</bool>
   </property>
   <property name="maximumSize">
    <size>
     <width>16777215</width>
     <height>16777215</height>
    </size>
   </property>
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>100</width>
     <height>30</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="whatsThis">
    <string/>
   </property>
   <property name="cursor">
    <cursorShape>ArrowCursor</cursorShape>
   </property>
   <property name="sizePolicy">
    <sizepolicy hsizetype="Preferred" vsizetype="Preferred">
     <horstretch>0</horstretch>
     <verstretch>0</verstretch>
    </sizepolicy>
   </property>
   <property name="focusPolicy">
    <enum>Qt::NoFocus</enum>
   </property>
   <property name="frameShadow">
    <enum>QFrame::Plain</enum>
   </property>
   <property name="textInteractionFlags">
    <enum>Qt::LinksAccessibleByMouse</enum>
   </property>
   <property name="enabled">
    <bool>true</bool>
   </property>
   <property name="frameShape">
    <enum>QFrame::NoFrame</enum>
   </property>
   <property name="autoFillBackground">
    <bool>false</bool>
   </property>
   <property name="windowModified">
    <bool>false</bool>
   </property>
   <property name="updatesEnabled">
    <bool>true</bool>
   </property>
   <property name="wordWrap">
    <bool>false</bool>
   </property>
   <property name="indent">
    <number>-1</number>
   </property>
   <property name="lineWidth">
    <number>1</number>
   </property>
   <property name="midLineWidth">
    <number>0</number>
   </property>
   <property name="toolTipDuration">
    <number>-1</number>
   </property>
   <property name="scaledContents">
    <bool>false</bool>
   </property>
   <property name="tabletTracking">
    <bool>false</bool>
   </property>
   <property name="contextMenuPolicy">
    <enum>Qt::DefaultContextMenu</enum>
   </property>
   <property name="locale">
    <locale language="English" country="UnitedKingdom"/>
   </property>
   <property name="windowIconText">
    <string/>
   </property>
   <property name="toolTip">
    <string/>
   </property>
   <property name="accessibleName">
    <string/>
   </property>
   <property name="pos" stdset="0">
    <point>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
    </point>
   </property>
   <property name="minimumWidth">
    <number>0</number>
   </property>
   <property name="windowFilePath">
    <string/>
   </property>
   <property name="maximumHeight">
    <number>16777215</number>
   </property>
   <property name="objectName">
    <string notr="true"/>
   </property>
   <property name="windowOpacity">
    <double>1.000000000000000</double>
   </property>
   <property name="mouseTracking">
    <bool>false</bool>
   </property>
   <property name="statusTip">
    <string/>
   </property>
   <property name="frameRect">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>100</width>
     <height>30</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="accessibleDescription">
    <string/>
   </property>
   <property name="inputMethodHints">
    <enum>Qt::ImhNone</enum>
   </property>
   <property name="acceptDrops">
    <bool>false</bool>
   </property>
   <property name="minimumSize">
    <size>
     <width>0</width>
     <height>0</height>
    </size>
   </property>
   <property name="minimumHeight">
    <number>0</number>
   </property>
   <property name="visible">
    <bool>false</bool>
   </property>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Here is my actual code:

```
import os
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtTest, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtDesigner import QFormBuilder
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QFrame, QGridLayout, QLabel, QMainWindow, QScrollArea, QWidget, QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtCore import QPoint, Qt, QIODevice, QFile
from PyQt5.Qt import QPixmap

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, obj=None, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        class MovableLabel(QLabel):
            """WToolBar is a personalized toolbar."""

            homeAction = None

            oldPos = QPoint()

            def __init__(self, mainWindow : MainWindow):
                super().__init__(mainWindow)
                self.mainWindow = mainWindow
                self.clicked = False

            def mousePressEvent(self, evt):
                """Select the toolbar."""
                self.oldPos = evt.globalPos()
                if not self.clicked:
                    globalPos = self.mapToGlobal(self.pos())
                    self.setParent(self.mainWindow)
                    self.move(self.mapFromGlobal(globalPos))
                    self.raise_()
                    self.show()
                    self.clicked = True
                    self.grabMouse()
                print('clicked')
                pass


            def mouseMoveEvent(self, evt):
                """Move the toolbar with mouse iteration."""
                delta = QPoint(evt.globalPos() - self.oldPos)
                self.move(self.x() + delta.x(), self.y() + delta.y())
                self.oldPos = evt.globalPos()

            def mouseReleaseEvent(self, ev: QtGui.QMouseEvent) -> None:
                self.releaseMouse()



        scrollArea = QScrollArea(self)
        widget = QWidget()
        scrollAreaLayout = QGridLayout()
        layout = QGridLayout()
        dir = r'C:\Users\abrah\Downloads\Players'
        pixmap = QPixmap()

        scrollArea.setWidget(widget)
        scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(True)
        scrollArea.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
        scrollArea.setFixedSize(500, 700)
        widget.setLayout(scrollAreaLayout)
        scrollAreaLayout.addWidget(QWidget(), 0, 2)

        for filename in os.listdir(dir):
            pixmap = QPixmap(dir + '\\' + filename).scaledToHeight(100, Qt.SmoothTransformation)
            label = MovableLabel(self)
            label.setPixmap(pixmap)
            label.setFixedSize(pixmap.width(), pixmap.height())
            scrollAreaLayout.addWidget(label)

        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: black;")
        self.showMaximized()
        formBuilder = QFormBuilder()
        file = QFile('line_up.ui')
        file.open(QFile.ReadWrite)
        formBuilder.save(file, self)
        file.close()

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

window = MainWindow()

app.exec_()
```

Could someone please explain why, and how I can fix this?

Comment: 1) Your loader and saver seem absolutely identical to me. 2) Are you completely sure you want to do this? Why do you need to "save and load it later"? Is it because you want to store data that the user had inserted? If that's so, using QFormBuilder is really *not* a good approach. 3) The line `widget = QWidget()` is completely useless, since you're overwriting it the next line. 4) Provide the ui file.

Comment: 2) yeah. How should I approach this? 3) Yeah it's just in case because the intellisense said that load() returns None. 4) I edited my post now.

Comment: 1) The file are still identical, can you clarify? 2) "Yeah" to what? 3) load() should return a QWidget that has the `self` as parent.

Comment: 1) Sorry, I fixed it now. 2) The user will move widgets around, so I want the program to save that.

Comment: Well, the fact is that QAbstractFormBuilder is intended to be used for designer plugins, not as a standalone way to load widgets. There are many reasons for which doing it like you are might be wrong, including the fact that, as the documentation says, `save()` writes **all** properties of the widget, not only the modified ones, and this can be an issue. That said, the reason is that using `save()` on `self` is that QFormBuilder is trying to create the class name (`Window`) which is not a known Qt class. Further more, you should not try to create a QMainWindow as child of a QWidget.

Comment: So what should I do to save a standalone dynamic form?

Comment: That depends. Is your customizable ui so complex that requires a QFormBuilder? Are you using custom nested layouts, advanced properties, etc? If that's so, then you *could* try to use it (but you need to do that in the right way), otherwise, just make a list of your widgets and their basic properties (geometry, possible editable values, etc) and serialize them in some way, for example using a json file.

Comment: I'm trying to make a soccer line up app, where you drag players around to make the line up.  The players are labels with pixmap. There are about 25 labels.

Comment: see my answer, but, honestly, considering what you're saying, using QFormBuilder is absolutely an overdoing. I'd suggest you to create a QLabel subclass for your players, and create a serialization method to store whatever property you need (including, obviously, position and pixmap), then restore them by unserializing those data. Seriously, even considering my answer, do **not** do that for your scenario, it's completely useless and also requires the designer plugin which is *not* included in the standard PyQt release.

Comment: Thanks for your extensive answer. You're right, saving the position in the label subclass is a much better idea. I notice you used eventFilter. What exactly is that? I know this is going beyond the forum question now, but would you be kind enough to check my actual code, and give me feedback?

Comment: How would I serialize and unserialize? You mentioned something about a json file?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, keep in mind that QFormBuilder is *not* normally intended to be used to restore the state of a widget, as it was created to save and restore contents of Qt Designer plugins.

With this in mind, consider that using it is *not* guaranteed to work, especially if you're using widgets that are not part of the standard Qt library or if you're using promoted widgets (it can be done, but they must be registered in the QFormLayout instance before that).

Unless you're using a very complex and extended interface with advanced drag&drop features to create the UI, I would discourage you to use this approach.

Now, the problem is that `QFormBuilder.load()` returns a widget that has the last argument given as its *parent*. In your case, this a problem for the following reasons:

1. A QMainWindow is not intended to be a children of another widget.
2. `QFormBuilder.save()` saves the target widget with its *class name*, since you're using a custom class (`Window`), Qt doesn't know anything about the `Window` class.

The easy workaround to your issue is to import that class at the beginning of your loader:

```
from saver import Window
```

But I'd suggest you to use a better approach.

First of all, a QMainWindow should **always** use a *central widget*, and everything should be a child of that widget.

Then, use a QMainWindow for the main class of your loader too, and load the new widget as the *new* central widget.

Also, remember that "free widgets" (widgets that are not added to a layout manager) are *not* shown if the widget has already been shown, and considering that *all* properties of a widget are saved by the QFormBuilder and you saved the form *before* showing the window, the result is that the children won't be shown anyway (because they have the visible property explicitly set as false).

Finally, I'm assuming that you want to save the QMainWindow in its entirety. Unfortunately, doing what you tried is not valid, for two reasons:

1. A QMainWindow should have no parent, so you cannot try to use a "subclassed" object to load it and possibly implement your own methods
2. Even if you try to create it as a child of the MyForm instance, you'll face lots of problems, most importantly you'll loose many of the features of a main window and will probably have unconsistent or unexpected behavior.

Depending on your needs, you could use a centralized QMainWindow subclass that can do both saving and restoring, or you could differentiate them and implement what you need.

In any case, remember that the saved and loaded object should be the central widget.

```
from PyQt5.QtDesigner import QFormBuilder
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from random import randrange

class Window(QMainWindow):
    startPos = None
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setMinimumSize(400, 300)

        fileMenu = self.menuBar().addMenu('File')
        restoreAction = fileMenu.addAction('Restore')
        restoreAction.triggered.connect(self.restore)
        saveAction = fileMenu.addAction('Save')
        saveAction.triggered.connect(self.save)

        central = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(central)

        for i in range(5):
            label = QLabel('label {}'.format(i + 1), central)
            label.move(randrange(300), randrange(200))
            label.installEventFilter(self)

    def restore(self):
        file = QFile('line_up.ui')
        file.open(QFile.ReadOnly)
        newWidget = QFormBuilder().load(file, self)
        self.setCentralWidget(newWidget)

    def save(self):        
        file = QFile('line_up.ui')
        file.open(QFile.WriteOnly)
        QFormBuilder().save(file, self.centralWidget())
        file.close()

    def eventFilter(self, source, event):
        if event.type() == event.MouseButtonPress and event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.startPos = event.pos()
        elif event.type() == event.MouseMove and self.startPos:
            source.move(source.pos() + (event.pos() - self.startPos))
            return True
        elif event.type() == event.MouseButtonRelease:
            self.startPos = None
        return super().eventFilter(source, event)

app = QApplication([])
mainWindow = Window()
mainWindow.show()
app.exec()
```

A revised version of your examples:

```
# saver.py
class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        central = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(central)

        label = QLabel(central, text='myForm')
        self.setWindowTitle('myTitle')
        self.show()
        
        formBuilder = QFormBuilder()
        file = QFile('line_up.ui')
        file.open(QFile.WriteOnly)
        formBuilder.save(file, central)
        file.close()


# loader.py
class MyForm(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        formBuilder = QFormBuilder()
        file = QFile('line_up.ui')
        file.open(QFile.ReadOnly)
        widget = formBuilder.load(file, self)
        file.close()
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)
```

Comment: 1) Did you do all this in 1 minute???
2) Why must it be in a central widget?